# Eclipse Junit '-ea' VM Option

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ide

In eclipse preferences

```
Windows > Preferences > Java > Junit
```

[image]

What effect does the "Add '-ea' to VM args ...." checkbox option actually have on the new junit launch config?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It enables the JVM to honour [assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10)

Comment: +1 note: the Java-in-built assertations are not the junit ones ... I do not recommend to use those in-built assert statements. instead do unit testing

Comment: @Karussell Assertions and unit tests serve different purposes. When writing unit tests, you should use the junit assert functions. Inside your regular code, you should use the assert keyword if you want to test invariants and other conditions (which is a good idea).